# Asp.Net Web API 2 test, response pending

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-web-api2

I'm testing out the Web Api 2 for my next project. Wrote a simple test but when I'm running it in debugger mode, the request is not invoking a response, it remains pending as far I can see in the DevTools network tab. .NET 4.7.1, VS 2017. I created a new project (MVC, API), added a Model, then a Controller, left the routing per default.

For the life of it, I can't figure out what's going wrong. This should be straight forward I guess.

Also, VS is trying to load a lot of Symbol info on start up.
Here is the code (as you can see, very basic test):

Model:

```
public class TestInfo
{
    public string x { get; set; }
    public string y { get; set; }
    public string z { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class TestInfoController : ApiController
{
    readonly TestInfo testinfo = new TestInfo() { x = "x", y = "y", z = "z" };

    public TestInfo GetTestInfo()
    {
        return testinfo;
    }
}
```

Routing in WebApiConfig.cs:

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "Api Default",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

I run it in debugger in VS2017, then just change the URL to `localhost:xxxxx/api/testinfo`.

Nothing happens, loads for quite a long time and returns a blank page. Not a 404 or 500. All pointers as to where to look would be appreciated.

Edited: return type TestInfo

I just run it in FF and the page just keeps loading 'Waiting for website'

EDIT 2: so I published to my local disk, set up IIS and tested like that. It worked. So somehow, it just does not want to run in debug mode from VS2017, which is very inconvenient.

Comment: Did you *pause* the debugger perhaps, or hit a breakpoint?

Comment: @GSerg Have you tried putting a breakpoint at the very start of the application? I believe it would be either the global.asax (.net framework) or program.cs (dot net core).

Comment: Your ´GetTestInfo()´ method is returning a string, so you should probably serialize your model class before returning it

Comment: That's correct, I changed it to TestInfo iso string

Comment: Where do I put a breakpoint? Where is the entrypoint of the app? Is it in class TestInfoController?

Comment: There is no index on the TestInfoController, i think that is the reason it returns a blank page

Comment: What do you mean by 'there is no index'?

Comment: testinfo variable is a complex type of TestInfo therefore cannot be returned as string. You should serialize your return as JSON if the function will return type of string.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api You can use a complex model to get the values, but you need to create an index.html page in order to see the result, as described on the link above

Comment: Better read a tutorial first , example: http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/webapi/create-web-api-project

Comment: I did, even followed it step by step, to no avail. I don't understand what is going on